# Using the rpc_access_data method Daemon RPC

Tags: monerod, rpc, monerod-commands

Monerod command:

```
monerod --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind --public-node --rpc-payment-address xxxxx --rpc-payment-credits 250 --rpc-payment-difficulty 1000
```

Curl request:

```
curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"rpc_access_data"}"
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": -32700,
    "message": "Parse error"
  },
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
```

How can I successful retrieve rpc payment information from monerod rpc?

Comment: Try without  --restricted-rpc, it's a priviledged RPC. Though I'd expect to see a 404 there, so it might not be that.

Comment: You can't run monerod with rpc payments without the rpc being restricted. It gives an error, saying that if you do this anyone can modify their credits.

Answer (score 0):

This method is not accessible via the json rpc yet.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/7178